# How do you find the percent of change for the Top 100 Customers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, basically this is the question that I'm trying to answer,

"Find top 100 customers and their average spend, average quantity by each year. Also find the percentage of change in their spend."

How do I find the percent of change by year? What I'm trying to do is to create different columns for each year and show the percent change with respect to the previous year.

For Example: "Spend_2003", Spend_2004"......., "Spend_2010" will be the different columns and that will be for each "Customer"

So far, I've got this:

```
select tier.Customer_Name, 
sum(case when tier.YEAR = 2003 then tier.Average_Spend end) * 100 / (select sum(one.tp) from (select Avg(TotalPrice) tp, YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)) one where one.YEAR=2003) as spend_2003,

sum(case when tier.YEAR = 2004 then tier.Average_Spend end) * 100 / (select sum(two.tp) from (select Avg(TotalPrice) tp, YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)) two where two.YEAR=2004) as spend_2004,

sum(case when tier.YEAR = 2005 then tier.Average_Spend end) * 100 / (select sum(three.tp) from (select Avg(TotalPrice) tp, YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)) three where three.YEAR=2005) as spend_2005,

sum(case when tier.YEAR = 2006 then tier.Average_Spend end) * 100 / (select sum(four.tp) from (select Avg(TotalPrice) tp, YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)) four where four.YEAR=2006) as spend_2006,

sum(case when tier.YEAR = 2007 then tier.Average_Spend end) * 100 / (select sum(five.tp) from (select Avg(TotalPrice) tp, YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)) five where five.YEAR=2007) as spend_2007,

sum(case when tier.YEAR = 2008 then tier.Average_Spend end) * 100 / (select sum(six.tp) from (select Avg(TotalPrice) tp,YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)) six where six.YEAR=2008) as spend_2008,

sum(case when tier.YEAR = 2009 then tier.Average_Spend end) * 100 / (select sum(seven.tp) from (select Avg(TotalPrice) tp, YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)) seven where seven.YEAR=2009) as spend_2009,

sum(case when tier.YEAR = 2010 then tier.Average_Spend end) * 100 / (select sum(eight.tp) from (select Avg(TotalPrice) as tp, YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)) eight where eight.YEAR=2010) as spend_2010

from (
select Top 100 Customer_Name, AVG(TotalPrice) as Average_Spend, AVG(Quantity) as Avg_Qty , YEAR(Date) as [YEAR] from DIM_CUSTOMER c inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS t on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date)
) tier
Group By tier.Customer_Name
```

I understand that It isn't exactly a percent change but I thought I'd try to find just the percentage first.

I also understand that I've messed up even that, incredibly so.

Below is the Data:

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_MANUFACTURER (
IDManufacturer INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(11, 1),
Manufacturer_Name VARCHAR (20)
)

CREATE TABLE DIM_MODEL (
IDModel INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(101, 1),
Model_Name VARCHAR(20),
Unit_price MONEY ,
IDManufacturer INT REFERENCES DIM_Manufacturer(IDManufacturer)
)

CREATE TABLE DIM_CUSTOMER (
IDCustomer INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(10001, 1),
Customer_Name VARCHAR(30),
Email VARCHAR (40),
Phone BIGINT
)

CREATE TABLE DIM_LOCATION (
IDLocation INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(2001, 1),
ZipCode INT ,
Country VARCHAR (20),
[State] VARCHAR (20),
City VARCHAR (20)
)

CREATE TABLE DIM_DATE (
[DATE] DATE PRIMARY KEY,
[YEAR] AS YEAR([DATE]),
[QUARTER] AS DATEPART(QUARTER, [DATE]),
[MONTH] AS MONTH([DATE])
)

CREATE TABLE FACT_TRANSACTIONS (
IDModel INT REFERENCES DIM_MODEL(IDModel),
IDCustomer INT REFERENCES DIM_CUSTOMER(IDCustomer),
IDLocation INT REFERENCES DIM_LOCATION(IDLocation),
Date DATE REFERENCES DIM_DATE([DATE]),
TotalPrice MONEY,
Quantity INT,
)

INSERT INTO DIM_Manufacturer VALUES 
('Apple'), ('Samsung'), ('One Plus'), ('Nokia'), ('Motorola'), ('HTC')

INSERT INTO DIM_MODEL VALUES
('iPhone 4', 377, '11'), 
('iPhone 4S', 414, '11'), 
('iPhone 5', 456, '11'), 
('iPhone 6', 501, '11'), 
('iPhone 7', 552, '11'), 
('Thunderbolt', 201, '16'), 
('C139', 121, '15'), 
('C200', 148, '15'), 
('Droid Bionic', 155, '15'), 
('RAZR V3', 81, '15'), 
('Motorola Z', 283, '15'), 
('3210', 14, '14'), 
('5230', 31, '14'), 
('6600', 47, '14'), 
('3310 (3330)', 28, '14'), 
('6010 (6020/6030)', 55, '14'), 
('6230 (6233)', 52, '14'), 
('E1100', 148, '12'), 
('E250', 168, '12'), 
('Galaxy Note II', 216, '12'), 
('Galaxy S', 175, '12'), 
('Galaxy S4', 283, '12'), 
('Galaxy S5', 391, '12'), 
('Galaxy S7', 432, '12'), 
('Galaxy S8', 662, '12'), 
('OnePlus X', 168, '13'), 
('OnePlus 2', 189, '13'), 
('OnePlus 5', 317, '13'), 
('OnePlus 5T', 405, '13'), 
('OnePlus 6T', 495, '13') 

INSERT INTO dim_Customer VALUES
('Kallie Blackwood', 'kallie.blackwood@abc.com', '4159170276'), 
('Johnetta Abdallah', 'johnetta_abdallah@abc.com', '9196014934'), 
('Bobbye Rhym', 'brhym@abc.com', '6505905578'), 
('Micaela Rhymes', 'micaela_rhymes@abc.com', '9251192329'), 
('Tamar Hoogland', 'tamar@abc.com', '7401061857'), 
('Moon Parlato', 'moon@abc.com', '5859253831'), 
('Laurel Reitler', 'laurel_reitler@abc.com', '4108683483'), 
('Delisa Crupi', 'delisa.crupi@abc.com', '9737571204'), 
('Viva Toelkes', 'viva.toelkes@abc.com', '7736528556'), 
('Elza Lipke', 'elza@abc.com', '9733365344'), 
('Devorah Chickering', 'devorah@abc.com', '5056458855'), 
('Timothy Mulqueen', 'timothy_mulqueen@abc.org', '7186066652'), 
('Arlette Honeywell', 'ahoneywell@abc.com', '9047469448'), 
('Dominque Dickerson', 'dominque.dickerson@abc.org', '5103067375'), 
('Lettie Isenhower', 'lettie_isenhower@abc.com', '2167709766'), 
('Myra Munns', 'mmunns@abc.net', '8174448751'), 
('Stephaine Barfield', 'stephaine@abc.com', '3108962764'), 
('Lai Gato', 'lai.gato@abc.org', '8479778728'), 
('Stephen Emigh', 'stephen_emigh@abc.com', '3305530535'), 
('Tyra Shields', 'tshields@abc.com', '2153025164'), 
('Tammara Wardrip', 'twardrip@abc.net', '6505352193'), 
('Cory Gibes', 'cory.gibes@abc.com', '6268825109'), 
('Danica Bruschke', 'danica_bruschke@abc.com', '2548757856'), 
('Wilda Giguere', 'wilda@abc.net', '9076724553'), 
('Elvera Benimadho', 'elvera.benimadho@abc.net', '4088708850'), 
('Carma Vanheusen', 'carma@abc.net', '5106621716'), 
('Malinda Hochard', 'malinda.hochard@abc.com', '3177685506')

INSERT INTO DIM_LOCATION VALUES
(85086, 'US', 'Arizona', 'Anthem'), (85117, 'US', 'Arizona', 'Apache Jct'), 
(94005, 'US', 'California', 'Brisbane'), (92703, 'US', 'California', 'Bristol'), 
(21163, 'US', 'Maryland', 'Woodstock'), (21648, 'US', 'Maryland', 'Woolford'), 
(122002, 'India', 'Haryana', 'Gurgaon'), (530068, 'India', 'Karnataka', 'Bangalore'), 
(110004, 'India', 'Delhi', 'Delhi'), (400006, 'India', 'Maharashtra', 'Mumbai')

INSERT INTO DIM_DATE VALUES
('02/15/2005'), ('10/23/2005'), ('02/26/2003'), ('05/25/2009'), ('04/16/2003'), ('11/03/2003'), 
('01/01/2010'), ('04/21/2007'), ('10/19/2010'), ('10/03/2010'), ('10/13/2010'), ('05/20/2003'), 
('02/04/2004'), ('10/22/2010'), ('03/23/2005'), ('02/11/2005'), ('10/08/2008'), ('10/06/2008'), 
('05/14/2006'), ('04/22/2010'), ('12/12/2005'), ('03/27/2010'), ('03/07/2007'), ('04/17/2006'), 
('10/01/2005'), ('09/18/2010'), ('10/06/2004'), ('03/27/2009'), ('07/09/2010'), ('05/04/2010'), 
('04/22/2004'), ('09/21/2005'), ('01/08/2008'), ('02/15/2009'), ('03/14/2007'), ('11/09/2009'), 
('02/21/2010'), ('10/04/2009'), ('07/05/2003'), ('01/04/2005'), ('08/04/2008'), ('08/02/2010'), 
('07/26/2009'), ('02/18/2006'), ('02/21/2009'), ('03/10/2004'), ('01/20/2007'), ('07/22/2006'), 
('05/19/2009'), ('04/14/2008'), ('08/09/2008'), ('07/18/2007'), ('03/26/2007'), ('08/06/2006'), 
('02/11/2003'), ('01/06/2005'), ('01/10/2006'), ('07/10/2004'), ('01/15/2004'), ('01/09/2005'), 
('07/25/2007'), ('04/21/2003'), ('05/19/2010'), ('02/15/2004'), ('06/04/2009'), ('08/12/2005'), 
('04/09/2010'), ('04/11/2008'), ('09/18/2003'), ('06/28/2005'), ('11/28/2003'), ('02/04/2010'), 
('09/04/2004'), ('05/05/2007'), ('05/07/2010'), ('07/16/2008'), ('02/05/2007'), ('10/20/2006'), 
('03/07/2008'), ('02/09/2005'), ('01/27/2007'), ('06/12/2006'), ('10/03/2008'), ('02/12/2005'), 
('05/15/2009'), ('08/27/2003'), ('10/19/2008'), ('02/26/2005'), ('09/05/2006'), ('04/03/2004'), 
('06/20/2004'), ('03/05/2008'), ('04/19/2008'), ('10/11/2007'), ('05/18/2010'), ('05/08/2007'), 
('02/08/2004'), ('04/27/2007'), ('09/03/2006'), ('03/19/2009'), ('11/01/2008'), ('08/01/2008'), 
('04/27/2006'), ('04/05/2005'), ('02/10/2009'), ('07/14/2006'), ('07/16/2005'), ('09/17/2006'), 
('04/02/2004'), ('10/24/2005'), ('05/18/2005'), ('05/25/2003'), ('03/09/2010'), ('02/18/2004'), 
('10/03/2006'), ('06/05/2003'), ('09/03/2007'), ('11/06/2007'), ('02/09/2006'), ('11/03/2006'), 
('07/23/2008'), ('06/24/2010'), ('11/13/2006'), ('08/18/2008'), ('05/06/2005'), ('12/21/2004'), 
('10/06/2006'), ('04/19/2009'), ('11/18/2004'), ('08/03/2006'), ('11/19/2005'), ('07/23/2010'), 
('01/21/2005'), ('09/13/2005'), ('06/22/2010'), ('06/02/2010'), ('10/13/2006'), ('08/01/2007'), 
('09/07/2006'), ('03/28/2009'), ('05/18/2007'), ('05/04/2005'), ('07/23/2004'), ('03/27/2007'),
('05/27/2006'), ('08/14/2010'), ('09/23/2010'), ('12/15/2006'), ('10/21/2004'), ('08/15/2003'), 
('08/19/2009'), ('01/16/2008'), ('09/24/2009'), ('07/17/2006'), ('01/27/2005'), ('10/08/2005'), 
('03/05/2007'), ('12/13/2006'), ('11/15/2007'), ('05/24/2003'), ('07/22/2008'), ('06/16/2003'), 
('01/03/2007'), ('01/05/2004'), ('12/28/2009'), ('01/24/2004'), ('02/26/2010'), ('02/03/2007'), 
('02/02/2008'), ('02/22/2005'), ('12/18/2004'), ('08/25/2003'), ('04/06/2007'), ('05/21/2003'), 
('06/23/2009'), ('05/25/2010'), ('09/27/2006'), ('02/17/2007'), ('08/08/2007'), ('11/18/2008'), 
('07/17/2007'), ('07/27/2009'), ('12/13/2007'), ('12/08/2004'), ('04/13/2004'), ('12/19/2008'), 
('06/14/2008'), ('11/06/2009'), ('06/01/2005'), ('05/05/2009'), ('07/03/2009'), ('12/20/2007'), 
('04/28/2007'), ('03/09/2003'), ('07/18/2008'), ('01/22/2005'), ('07/01/2009'), ('08/18/2004'), 
('02/09/2004'), ('08/25/2004'), ('04/25/2010'), ('04/05/2007'), ('02/07/2003'), ('11/15/2010'), 
('09/28/2007'), ('02/03/2009'), ('06/03/2008'), ('03/02/2008'), ('12/19/2003'), ('12/13/2005'), 
('06/16/2008'), ('08/03/2003'), ('07/26/2005'), ('10/11/2010'), ('10/20/2007'), ('12/22/2007'), 
('01/27/2008'), ('05/07/2008'), ('01/25/2007'), ('07/28/2006'), ('02/16/2004'), ('12/12/2006'), 
('07/10/2003'), ('09/14/2009'), ('09/02/2010'), ('07/13/2008')


    INSERT INTO FACT_TRANSACTIONS VALUES                        
    (117,10002,2003,'10/13/2010',54,1),
    (104,10002,2008,'02/15/2004',503,1),
    (124,10003,2009,'10/03/2010',435,1),
    (104,10004,2002,'09/04/2004',504,1),
    (118,10006,2003,'02/21/2010',300,2),
    (123,10007,2009,'10/20/2006',392,1),    
    (106,10008,2006,'10/06/2004',205,1),
    (121,10008,2003,'03/27/2009',179,1),
    (112,10009,2006,'05/14/2006',18,1),
    (110,10009,2001,'03/26/2007',82,1),
    (118,10009,2002,'07/10/2004',151,1),
    (122,10011,2002,'06/04/2009',286,1),
    (118,10012,2010,'04/21/2007',149,1),
    (106,10012,2006,'05/07/2010',202,1),
    (104,10013,2004,'01/06/2005',505,1),
    (113,10014,2005,'10/06/2008',33,1),
    (114,10015,2001,'02/15/2005',52,1),
    (119,10016,2002,'09/21/2005',173,1),
    (123,10017,2007,'04/22/2010',393,1),
    (101,10018,2006,'02/11/2005',381,1),
    (107,10018,2010,'10/08/2008',122,1),
    (101,10019,2001,'02/21/2009',380,1),
    (126,10022,2005,'11/03/2003',169,1),
    (118,10022,2007,'04/21/2003',153,1),
    (101,10022,2009,'11/28/2003',380,1),
    (114,10023,2007,'04/17/2006',52,1),
    (101,10023,2008,'10/04/2009',760,2),
    (101,10023,2009,'05/19/2010',382,1),
    (112,10024,2010,'03/23/2005',17,1),
    (124,10024,2008,'07/18/2007',435,1),
    (108,10024,2007,'02/05/2007',151,1),
    (126,10025,2009,'01/08/2008',173,1),
    (122,10025,2005,'07/05/2003',858,3),
    (112,10025,2006,'01/20/2007',16,1),
    (110,10025,2005,'01/09/2005',85,1),
    (122,10026,2008,'08/06/2006',285,1),
    (110,10027,2003,'10/23/2005',84,1),
    (103,10027,2006,'03/27/2010',457,1),
    (108,10027,2004,'05/04/2010',153,1),
    (123,10027,2006,'02/15/2009',394,1),
    (107,10027,2009,'05/19/2009',125,1)
```

Comment: You may be better served with a smaller and more concise data sample data and desired results

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I've shortened it.

Comment: There is issue with data FACT_TRANSACTIONS  has references, but required reference tables does not have reference data inserted

Comment: @DeepakKumar It references to Model, Customer, Location, and Date. And all of them have data inserted and none of them are empty. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @ab8895 it is not empty the issue is customer table has identity created while inserting, while in fact table when you insert customer id that is not present, it is different

Comment: @DeepakKumar I'm sorry but I'm confused about what you just said, Could you elaborate more on the issue? Or give me some kind of reference, so that I can read more about it?

Comment: @ab8895 there is no issue with your tables, only issue is data . If you see  IDCustomer INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(10001, 1). In inset data you have 27 records,  so id will be max 10027, but in your Fact insert data you have customer id like 10038, 10044. SO insert fails

Comment: @DeepakKumar I see now. I randomly shortened the data for the sake of simplicity but failed to see what I actually did. Could you now tell me how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a minimal working example, with only the tables that are absolutely necessary and no more than 3-4 rows of data for each table. In any case, could it be a pivot that you actually need to do here?

Comment: How do you exactly mean by "top 100"? Is it sorted by average spend, total spend, unit price or other quantity? Does the list vary each year or simply calculate over all years? If a top customer in 2005 falls out of the list in 2006, do we still keep that customer for all future years? There is too much ambiguity, please clarify for people to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I provide assumes the following.

1. "Top customers" are defined by `Average_Spend` for each distinct year. This may or may not make sense in real business cases (total_spend seems more reasonable). But this is beyond the scope of programming and can be changed easily.
2. The "top customers" are recomputed for each year. This also may or may not serve the business purpose, but it is a very common practice for making yearly reports. Adjustment on this is also easy.

The keys to the problem are:

1. Assign [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) at appropriate places to give rankings.
2. The matching logic is actually quite straightforward: a top customer this year to the same customer next year. A left join on `customer_name` and `year` would easily work.
3. By explicitly creating temp tables (begins with `#`) to save the intermediate results, the logic can be more understandable and maintainable. For instance, step 2 and step 3 can be easily merged with [common table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but by keeping them separated the code looks much organized.

**Solution**

```
use [testdb];
GO

/* parameters */

declare @top_amount int = 4;  -- top N

/* 1. List of the summary info of customers by year */

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#all_customers') is not null
    drop table #all_customers;

select
    Customer_Name, 
    AVG(TotalPrice) as Average_Spend, 
    AVG(Quantity) as Avg_Qty,
    YEAR(Date) as [YEAR],
    ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by YEAR(Date)
                      order by AVG(TotalPrice) desc) as rn
into #all_customers
from DIM_CUSTOMER as c 
inner join FACT_TRANSACTIONS as t
    on c.IDCustomer = t.IDCustomer
Group By Customer_Name, YEAR(Date);

--select * from #all_customers order by [YEAR], Average_Spend desc;

/* 2. List of top customers by year */

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#top_customers') is not null
    drop table #top_customers;

-- If other selection criteria for the legal top customers exist, it would
-- be more maintainable to not squeeze everything in a CTE in the next step.
select *
into #top_customers
from #all_customers
where rn <= @top_amount;

--select * from #top_customers order by [YEAR], Average_Spend desc;


/* 3. track yearly change for each year */

select
    L.Customer_Name,
    L.Year,
    L.Average_Spend,
    L.rn,
    R.Year as [Year_next],
    R.Average_Spend as Average_Spend_next,
    R.rn as rn_next,
    1.0 * R.Average_Spend / L.Average_Spend - 1.0 as diff
from #top_customers as L
left join #all_customers as R
    on L.Customer_Name = R.Customer_Name
    and R.[YEAR] = L.[YEAR] + 1;

-- cleanup
drop table #top_customers, #all_customers;
```

**Result** (top 4)

```
| Customer_Name      | Year | Average_Spend | rn | Year_next | Average_Spend_next | rn_next | diff                 |
|--------------------|------|---------------|----|-----------|--------------------|---------|----------------------|
| Elvera Benimadho   | 2003 | 858.0000      | 1  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Cory Gibes         | 2003 | 234.0000      | 2  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Micaela Rhymes     | 2004 | 504.0000      | 1  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Johnetta Abdallah  | 2004 | 503.0000      | 2  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Delisa Crupi       | 2004 | 205.0000      | 3  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Viva Toelkes       | 2004 | 151.0000      | 4  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Arlette Honeywell  | 2005 | 505.0000      | 1  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Lai Gato           | 2005 | 381.0000      | 2  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Myra Munns         | 2005 | 173.0000      | 3  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Elvera Benimadho   | 2005 | 85.0000       | 4  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Laurel Reitler     | 2006 | 392.0000      | 1  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Carma Vanheusen    | 2006 | 285.0000      | 2  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Danica Bruschke    | 2006 | 52.0000       | 3  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Viva Toelkes       | 2006 | 18.0000       | 4  | 2007      | 82.0000            | 3       | 3.55555555555555555  |
| Wilda Giguere      | 2007 | 293.0000      | 1  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Timothy Mulqueen   | 2007 | 149.0000      | 2  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Viva Toelkes       | 2007 | 82.0000       | 3  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Elvera Benimadho   | 2007 | 16.0000       | 4  | 2008      | 173.0000           | 1       | 9.81250000000000000  |
| Elvera Benimadho   | 2008 | 173.0000      | 1  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Lai Gato           | 2008 | 122.0000      | 2  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Dominque Dickerson | 2008 | 33.0000       | 3  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Danica Bruschke    | 2009 | 760.0000      | 1  | 2010      | 382.0000           | 3       | -0.49736842105263158 |
| Stephen Emigh      | 2009 | 380.0000      | 2  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Devorah Chickering | 2009 | 286.0000      | 3  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Malinda Hochard    | 2009 | 259.5000      | 4  | 2010      | 305.0000           | 4       | 0.17533718689788053  |
| Bobbye Rhym        | 2010 | 435.0000      | 1  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Stephaine Barfield | 2010 | 393.0000      | 2  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Danica Bruschke    | 2010 | 382.0000      | 3  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
| Malinda Hochard    | 2010 | 305.0000      | 4  | NULL      | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                 |
```

Tested on SQL Server 2017 (linux docker image, latest version)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
   enter code here

    SELECT 
    T1.Customer_Name, T1.Year, T1.Avg_Price,T1.Avg_Qty,
    CASE
        WHEN T2.Year IS NOT NULL
        THEN FORMAT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),(T1.Avg_Price-T2.Avg_Price))/CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),T2.Avg_Price),'p') ELSE NULL 
        END AS 'YEARLY_%_CHANGE'
    FROM
        (SELECT t2.Customer_Name, YEAR(t1.DATE) AS YEAR, AVG(t1.TotalPrice) AS Avg_Price, AVG(t1.Quantity) AS Avg_Qty FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS AS t1 
        left join DIM_CUSTOMER as t2 ON t1.IDCustomer=t2.IDCustomer
        where t1.IDCustomer in (select top 10 IDCustomer from FACT_TRANSACTIONS group by IDCustomer order by SUM(TotalPrice) desc)
        group by t2.Customer_Name, YEAR(t1.Date)
        )T1
    left join
        (SELECT t2.Customer_Name, YEAR(t1.DATE) AS YEAR, AVG(t1.TotalPrice) AS Avg_Price, AVG(t1.Quantity) AS Avg_Qty FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS AS t1 
        left join DIM_CUSTOMER as t2 ON t1.IDCustomer=t2.IDCustomer
        where t1.IDCustomer in (select top 10 IDCustomer from FACT_TRANSACTIONS group by IDCustomer order by SUM(TotalPrice) desc)
        group by t2.Customer_Name, YEAR(t1.Date)
        )T2
        on T1.Customer_Name=T2.Customer_Name and T2.YEAR=T1.YEAR-1 -- self join`








Customer_Name   Year    Avg_Price   Avg_Qty YEARLY_%_CHANGE
Arlene Klusman  2004    665.00  1   NULL
Arlene Klusman  2006    415.00  1   NULL
Arlene Klusman  2008    347.00  1   NULL
Arlene Klusman  2010    476.00  1   NULL
Bobbye Rhym 2005    319.00  1   NULL
Bobbye Rhym 2006    474.00  1   48.59%
Bobbye Rhym 2007    1106.00 2   133.33%
Bobbye Rhym 2008    322.00  1   -70.89%
Bobbye Rhym 2009    442.00  1   37.27%
Bobbye Rhym 2010    435.00  1   -1.58%
Celeste Korando 2003    283.00  1   NULL
Celeste Korando 2004    461.00  1   62.90%
Celeste Korando 2005    31.00   1   -93.28%
Celeste Korando 2006    401.6666    1   1,195.71%
Celeste Korando 2009    613.00  1   NULL
Celeste Korando 2010    396.00  1   -35.40%
Cory Gibes  2003    284.00  1   NULL
Cory Gibes  2004    503.00  1   77.11%
Cory Gibes  2005    202.00  1   -59.84%
Cory Gibes  2010    390.00  1   NULL
Dominque Dickerson  2004    56.00   1   NULL
Dominque Dickerson  2005    338.00  2   503.57%
Dominque Dickerson  2006    406.00  2   20.12%
Dominque Dickerson  2007    920.00  2   126.60%
Dominque Dickerson  2008    255.00  1   -72.28%
Edna Miceli 2003    172.00  1   NULL
Edna Miceli 2004    324.3333    1   88.56%
Edna Miceli 2005    246.6666    1   -23.95%
Edna Miceli 2008    553.00  1   NULL
Edna Miceli 2009    372.00  3   -32.73%
Edna Miceli 2010    314.00  2   -15.59%
Laurel Reitler  2003    410.00  1   NULL
Laurel Reitler  2005    149.00  1   NULL
Laurel Reitler  2006    226.00  1   51.68%
Laurel Reitler  2007    288.00  1   27.43%
Laurel Reitler  2008    557.00  1   93.40%
Laurel Reitler  2009    1528.00 4   174.33%
Laurel Reitler  2010    35.00   1   -97.71%
Moon Parlato    2003    667.00  1   NULL
Moon Parlato    2004    256.50  1   -61.54%
Moon Parlato    2009    823.50  2   NULL
Moon Parlato    2010    226.50  1   -72.50%
Pamella Schmierer   2004    458.00  1   NULL
Pamella Schmierer   2005    435.00  1   -5.02%
Pamella Schmierer   2007    17.00   1   NULL
Pamella Schmierer   2008    378.20  1   2,124.71%
Pamella Schmierer   2010    205.50  1   NULL
Sue Kownacki    2004    286.00  1   NULL
Sue Kownacki    2005    489.75  1   71.24%
Sue Kownacki    2006    173.00  1   -64.68%
Sue Kownacki    2008    285.00  1   NULL
Sue Kownacki    2009    159.00  1   -44.21%
Sue Kownacki    2010    298.6666    1   87.84%

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```